# Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, parsing

I have a small problem here. When I tried to do the following steps,

```
string set1="123.10,134.40";
string set2="17,134"; 
List<string> List1 = new List<string>(set1.Split(','));
List<string> List2 = new List<string>(set2.Split(','));

var QueryResult = from D1 in List1 
                  from E1 in List2
                  select new
                  {
                      D1,
                      E1
                  };
DataTable tempDT = new DataTable();
tempDT.Columns.Add("Data1", typeof(int));
tempDT.Columns.Add("Data2", typeof(string));

foreach (var item in QueryResult)
{
    tempDT.Rows.Add(new object[] {Convert.ToInt32(item.E1.ToString()),
    Convert.ToString(item.D1.ToString()) });
}
```

When I try to add those values to the `tempDT` I am getting an exception:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: That is most likely coming from `Convert.ToInt32`, what does `item.E1` look like? Is it a string that can be converted into a number?  
  
What is the whole stack trace?

Comment: Also E1 and D1 are both already strings, so the calls to `ToString` aren't needed.

Comment: what is the value of "item.E1" when you attempt to convert it to Int 32?

Comment: System.FormatException was unhandled by user code
  Message="Input string was not in a correct format."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is because you are using Convert.ToInt32 on a string that contains a decimal character.

Comment: You did not have to question it. I am pretty sure that IS the problem :)

Answer (score 3):

The code you posted worked just fine, so it means the problem is with your real data.

Most likely, you have something like this:

```
string set2="17,134,,20";
```

Meaning empty item which will crash the code.

Remove such empty items with:

```
List<string> List2 = new List<string>(set2.Split(new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

To be totally safe from that error, use TryParse instead:

```
int e1;
foreach (var item in QueryResult)
{
    if (Int32.TryParse(item.E1, out e1))
    {
        tempDT.Rows.Add(new object[] { e1, item.D1 });
    }
}
```

This will just ignore any invalid values, not adding them to the data table.